# How To Access third model with Where Clause Like where in inner JOIN

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3Table.

kelas - kelas_jurusan - jadwal_pelajaran

if I am using Query I use this

```
Select * From jadwal_pelajaran inner join kelasjurusan on jadwal_pelajaran.kelasjurusan_id = kelasjurusan.id inner join kelas on kelas.id = kelasjurusan.kelas_id WHERE kelas.id = 1;
```

How to transform to eloquent?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) ?

Comment: I believe you're searching for `hasManyThrough` feature.

Answer (score 0):

By using JadwalPelajaran model you can do like this and the rest is the names of your original tables

> JadwalPelajaran::join("kelas_jurusan","kelas_jurusan.id","=","jadwal_pelajaran.kelasjurusan_id")->join("kelas","kelas.id","=","kelasjurusan.kelas_id")->where("kelas.id","=",1)->get()

Hope it works :)